# How to do step by step J2ME debugging in netbeans

Tags: debugging, java-me, netbeans-6.9

I am not able to execute step by step debugging in netbeans for J2ME...

Can someone explain me the process or suggest a better debugger for J2ME

Answer (score 1):

Have look at this document [Mobility Modules for NetBeans](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7205809/NetBeans-J2ME-Tutorial#outer_page_39)